# How to hide the package name in toast message?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to remove the package name(Javascript) before toast message?

Package name:

```
com.company.javascript
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_hello).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post full code it's hard to understand why toast showing your Package name.

Comment: Can you try with `this` or `Activityname.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @Ashish, yes, I try the `Activityname.this`, but it still the same problem

Comment: Can you post full code of that function ?

Comment: "Javascript:" can't be the package name

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, it's not the point, I change it as some others, it still the same problem

Comment: I suspect that the "Javascript" is referring to your activity title, and it is being put there because your device manufacturer modified the behavior of `Toast`. You will not see that in most devices. I recommend simply not using `Toast`.

Comment: @AlenLee No, it is not the point, but you are giving wrong info in your question and in your title. We are trying to understand the issue and it is not related to the package name.

Comment: may be @CommonsWare is right, try with different mobile phone and check if the problem occurs.

Comment: @CommonsWare, maybe you are right

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @CommonsWare, this problem cause by some device manufacturer modified the behavior of `Toast`, so if necessary to do that, we have to override the `Toast.makeText` then show it

```
public class ToastUtils {

    public static void showToast(Context context, String message, int duration) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) toast.getView();
        TextView tvMessage = (TextView) group.getChildAt(0);
        tvMessage.setText(message);
        tvMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```